# Multiple buttons only showing button's content

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to work with HTML Buttons, but the problem is that I can't seem to get them to work together right. I'll put the code in twice, but It only works for one button's content. No matter which button I press (And yes, It does show multiple buttons) it only shows the content of one of them. The question I have is this: What do I have to change to make the buttons work individually of each other?

```
<div id="spoiler" style="display:none">

This is the code I use.

</div>
<button title="Click to show/hide content" type="button" onclick="if(document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display=='none') {document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display=''}else{document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display='none'}">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

> The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp)

If you have 2 you need different ID's

```html
<div id="spoiler" style="display:none">

  This is the code I use.

</div>
<button title="Click to show/hide content" type="button" onclick="if(document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display=='none') {document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display=''}else{document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display='none'}">Test</button>

<div id="spoiler2" style="display:none">

  This is the code I use. 2

</div>
<button title="Click to show/hide content" type="button" onclick="if(document.getElementById('spoiler2') .style.display=='none') {document.getElementById('spoiler2') .style.display=''}else{document.getElementById('spoiler2') .style.display='none'}">Test</button>
```

I also suggest to use a least use a function for this, example:

```js
function toggleDiv(el) {
  if (document.getElementById(el).style.display == 'none') {
    document.getElementById(el).style.display = ''
  } else {
    document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'none'
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="spoiler" style="display:none">

  This is the code I use.

</div>
<button title="Click to show/hide content" type="button" onclick="toggleDiv('spoiler')">Test</button>

<div id="spoiler2" style="display:none">

  This is the code I use. 2

</div>
<button title="Click to show/hide content" type="button" onclick="toggleDiv('spoiler2')">Test</button>
```

For ending there are more beautiful solution specially with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

In the first place, use jQuery -- it's faster to type than raw js, and immediately cross-browser.

Secondly, don't use inline javascript. It's much more difficult to read and troubleshoot. *(The below script can be inserted right in amongst the html code)*

Next, link your button to the elements it should operate on via IDs, as here:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#btnSpoiler').click(function(){
            $('#spoiler').toggle();
        });

    });
</script>
<div id="spoiler" style="display:none">
    This is the code I use.
</div>

<button id="btnSpoiler" title="Click to show/hide content">Show</button>
```

Actually, `link` is probably the wrong word -- there is nothing special about the IDs per se -- I am referring to the fact that by reading the code you can easily see which button goes with which element.

However, note how the DIV was controlled via its ID.

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/nyayx6L7/1/)</kbd>

---

Reasons to avoid inline javascript:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86589/why-should-i-avoid-inline-scripting

http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/