# How to enable an input by clicking a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have inventory list, I want to create invitation from the list.
All products have 2 inputs: `price` and `counts (qtys)` that are disabled.

I tried to create function that make the inputs enabled when the user clicked on the checkbox, but it's working only after 2 clicks...

```js
function niv(id)
{
    $("input:checkbox").click(function() {
        $('#'+id).attr("disabled", !this.checked); 
        $('#p'+id).attr("disabled", !this.checked); 
    });
}
```

The HTML:

```html
<tr class="even">

    <td>225/45/17</td>

    <td id=Bridgestone>Bridgestone</td>

    <td>Putenza <h6>91y</h6></td>

    <td><input type="text" id="p21" name="price[]" value="" disabled="disabled" /> <br /><small>מחיר מומלץ: 650</small> ₪</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="21" onclick="niv(21)"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="21" name="counts[]" disabled="disabled" /><small> מתוך 4 במלאי</small></td>

</tr>
<tr class="even">

    <td>225/45/19</td>

    <td id=Bridgestone>Bridgestone</td>

    <td>Putenza <h6>96w</h6></td>

    <td><input type="text" id="p20" name="price[]" value="" disabled="disabled" /> <br /><small>מחיר מומלץ: 1100</small> ₪</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="20" onclick="niv(20)"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="20" name="counts[]" disabled="disabled" /><small> מתוך 4 במלאי</small></td>

</tr>
<tr class="even">

    <td>225/55/17</td>

    <td id=Bridgestone>Bridgestone</td>

    <td>Turanza runflat <h6>97y</h6></td>

    <td><input type="text" id="p18" name="price[]" value="" disabled="disabled" /> <br /><small>מחיר מומלץ: 850</small> ₪</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="18" onclick="niv(18)"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="18" name="counts[]" disabled="disabled" /><small> מתוך 9 במלאי</small></td>

</tr>
<tr class="even">

    <td>225/55/18</td>

    <td id=Bridgestone>Bridgestone</td>

    <td>t001 <h6>98v</h6></td>

    <td><input type="text" id="p19" name="price[]" value="" disabled="disabled" /> <br /><small>מחיר מומלץ: 550-600</small> ₪</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="19" onclick="niv(19)"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="19" name="counts[]" disabled="disabled" /><small> מתוך 4 במלאי</small></td>

</tr>
<tr class="even">

    <td>255/50/20</td>

    <td id=Bridgestone>Bridgestone</td>

    <td>Hp Sport <h6>109v</h6></td>

    <td><input type="text" id="p14" name="price[]" value="" disabled="disabled" /> <br /><small>מחיר מומלץ: 850</small> ₪</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="14" onclick="niv(14)"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="14" name="counts[]" disabled="disabled" /><small> מתוך 4 במלאי</small></td>

</tr>
```

Comment: Darren L is right - get rid of inline js (remove all the `onclick=` attributes). DL's code works great, and his analysis/explanation of the problem is well done. See refs at bottom of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34834457/multiple-buttons-only-showing-buttons-content/34834537#34834537)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your niv function is wrong. Try to change it to:

```
function niv(id)
{
   var isCheck = $("input:checkbox[value='" + id + "']").is(':checked');
   $('#'+id).prop("disabled", !isCheck);
   $('#p'+id).prop("disabled", !isCheck);
}
```

Another possible solution is to pass the this value to the niv function in the call:

```
onclick="niv(this)"
```

And so the new niv function will be:

```
function niv(obj)
{
   $('#'+obj.value).prop("disabled", !obj.checked);
   $('#p'+obj.value).prop("disabled", !obj.checked);
}
```

My snippet:

```js
function niv(id)
{
  var isCheck = $("input:checkbox[value='" + id + "']").is(':checked');
  $('#'+id).prop("disabled", !isCheck);
  $('#p'+id).prop("disabled", !isCheck);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<table>
    <tr class="even">

        <td>225/45/17</td>

        <td id=Bridgestone>Bridgestone</td>

        <td>Putenza <h6>91y</h6></td>

        <td><input type="text" id="p21" name="price[]" value="" disabled="disabled" /> <br /><small>מחיר מומלץ: 650</small> ₪</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="21" onclick="niv(21)"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="21" name="counts[]" disabled="disabled" /><small> מתוך 4 במלאי</small></td>

    </tr><tr class="even">

    <td>225/45/19</td>

    <td id=Bridgestone>Bridgestone</td>

    <td>Putenza <h6>96w</h6></td>

    <td><input type="text" id="p20" name="price[]" value="" disabled="disabled" /> <br /><small>מחיר מומלץ: 1100</small> ₪</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="20" onclick="niv(20)"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="20" name="counts[]" disabled="disabled" /><small> מתוך 4 במלאי</small></td>

</tr><tr class="even">

    <td>225/55/17</td>

    <td id=Bridgestone>Bridgestone</td>

    <td>Turanza runflat <h6>97y</h6></td>

    <td><input type="text" id="p18" name="price[]" value="" disabled="disabled" /> <br /><small>מחיר מומלץ: 850</small> ₪</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="18" onclick="niv(18)"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="18" name="counts[]" disabled="disabled" /><small> מתוך 9 במלאי</small></td>

</tr><tr class="even">

    <td>225/55/18</td>

    <td id=Bridgestone>Bridgestone</td>

    <td>t001 <h6>98v</h6></td>

    <td><input type="text" id="p19" name="price[]" value="" disabled="disabled" /> <br /><small>מחיר מומלץ: 550-600</small> ₪</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="19" onclick="niv(19)"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="19" name="counts[]" disabled="disabled" /><small> מתוך 4 במלאי</small></td>

</tr><tr class="even">

    <td>255/50/20</td>

    <td id=Bridgestone>Bridgestone</td>

    <td>Hp Sport <h6>109v</h6></td>

    <td><input type="text" id="p14" name="price[]" value="" disabled="disabled" /> <br /><small>מחיר מומלץ: 850</small> ₪</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="14" onclick="niv(14)"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="14" name="counts[]" disabled="disabled" /><small> מתוך 4 במלאי</small></td>

</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the change() event listener, it's better for this purpose.
As the checkbox is in a table, I've just found the parent <tr> and then found all the text inputs within that row.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
  $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="text"]').attr("disabled", !this.checked);
})
```

You'll notice that this does away with the inline call to JavaScript, abstracting your JS code from your HTML. It also means that you don't need to be concerned with IDs and making sure they are sensible - possibly reducing BE workload and making everything more simple.

The reason that your code didn't work - and more specifically why it required two clicks is as follows:

You have an inline click event - which then calls a function to set a listener. Only when your inline click is called, is the listener applied.

The second time you click the new listener - with your logic - has been created, which means that it's used.

Additionally, every time you click on this checkbox element, you create a new listener - which means that within a couple of clicks, there is a big list of duplicated event listeners.

jsFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/likestothink/kgL4q0jg/